# RSA key pair generator applet, generate fixed almost zero private and public keys

Tags: java, rsa, javacard

I wrote the below JavaCard applet to generate `512` bit RSA public and private key pairs on the card and transfer them through the APDU responses to the outside:

```java
public class CryptoRSA extends Applet {

    //Abbreviations
    private static final boolean NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS = false;

    //arrays for generated keys in byte. (I know that 64 byte is enough)
    byte[] publicKey = new byte[128];
    byte[] privateKey = new byte[128];

    //Switch case parameters for selecting instruction =  INS in apdu command
    private static final byte GENERATE_KEY_PAIR = (byte) 0xC0;

    //Create object of keys
    RSAPrivateKey thePrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PRIVATE, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
    RSAPublicKey thePublickKey = (RSAPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
    KeyPair theKeyPair = new KeyPair(thePublickKey, thePrivateKey);

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new CryptoRSA();
    }

    protected CryptoRSA() {
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        short privateKeySize = 0;
        short publicKeySize = 0;
        byte[] publicArray;
        byte[] privateArray;
        try {
            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

                case GENERATE_KEY_PAIR:

                    theKeyPair.genKeyPair();

                    PrivateKey thePrivateKey = theKeyPair.getPrivate();
                    PublicKey thePublicKey = theKeyPair.getPublic();

                    publicKeySize = thePublicKey.getSize();
                    privateKeySize = thePrivateKey.getSize();

             //In the first program I used the followin transient arrays,
             //... and output was zero always. As I was thought
             //... that the origin of my problem is these transient arrays,
             //... (I think we cannot copy transient array to APDU buffer, Am I right?)
             //... I use above global arrays, but the problem remained
             //... as the first program.  

             //       byte[] publicKey = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) (publicKeySize / 8), JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
             //       byte[] privateKey = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) (privateKeySize / 8), JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

                    ((RSAPublicKey) thePublicKey).getExponent(publicKey, (short) 0);
                    ((RSAPrivateKey) thePrivateKey).getExponent(privateKey, (short) 0);


                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(publicKey, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, (short) (publicKeySize / 8));
                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(privateKey, (short) 0, buffer, (short) publicKeySize, (short) (privateKeySize / 8));
                    apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) ((short)(publicKeySize+privateKeySize) / 8));
                    break;

                default:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            short r = e.getReason();
            ISOException.throwIt(r);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that the output is fixed and is almost zero always :

```java
OpenSC:: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a40400060102030405DD -s 00c00000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 DD
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C0 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................

OpenSC:: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a40400060102030405DD -s 00c00000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 DD
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C0 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
```

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? Private keys are supposed to be private. Why are you transferring them anywhere?

Comment: @EJP I don't want to transfer it in my real projects. In this program I just want to check correctness of card's cryptography functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may notice, the returned values are not all zeros. The first 3 bytes of the response contains the exponent. What's wrong is your usage of `getSize()` method. This method actually returns the key size `KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512` and not the size of the key component. The size of the exponent is the returned value of `getExponent()` method.

You can retrieve the length of the public exponent by doing this:

```
publicKeySize = ((RSAPublicKey) thePublicKey).getExponent(publicKey, (short) 0);
```

You can do the same with the private exponent.

FYI, an RSA exponent = '01 00 01' is very common so I am confident that it was the generated exponent of your code.

Comment: But I need the length of public and private key before calling `getExponent()` method. I need it to define `publicKey` byte array.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to define a temporary byte array to retrieve the keys. You can directly use the APDU buffer instead. So, I don't see a need to use getSize() in your code.

Comment: You are right. But what happens if I have an RSA key pair that is larger than the card's buffer size?

Comment: Moreover, It doesn't convinced me that the wrong length for the key is the reason of having a fixed-zero key? (Not for the RSA Public Exponent)

Comment: If RSA key data bytes is larger than the card's buffer size, the `Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic` method will raise Boundary exception

Comment: You can try your code on the jcop simulator, the exponent is zero-fixed or not, different implementation of the java card os;

Comment: As I have mentioned, the RSA public exponent = 01 00 01 is very common and I am not surprised if you get this value all of the time. Instead of checking the contents of the exponent, you can check the modulus instead. You can see that the generated modulus is not fixed. Can you try this and tell me if it works?